# Formal definition of generalized probability density functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Is there a formal reference that defines *generalized probability density* functions? In particular, I'd like to use this to represent the PDF of a CDF that can have a finite number of jumps. I am not sure how to define the range of such a PDF formally.

I have found this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) but it doesn't specify how to represent the range of such functions

Comment: Does the Lebesgue decomposition theorem do what you want?

Comment: Yes, seems like it does! Thank you